# Wikipedia web scraping having issue with tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup,Tag
import requests

f=open("temples.txt","a+")

url=r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = Soup(r.content,"html.parser" )

temple_span=soup.find("span",{"id":"Births"})
temples_ul=temple_span.parent.find_next_sibling()


for item in temples_ul.findAll('li'):
    if isinstance(item,Tag):
        print (item.text)
```

But if there is some extra data between li and span it is not working. Example: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_tourist_attractions`

code:

```
</span></span></h3>
<div class="thumb tright"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:222px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg" class="image"><img alt="" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg/220px-Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg" decoding="async" width="220" height="275" class="thumbimage" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg/330px-Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg/440px-Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg 2x" data-file-width="2400" data-file-height="3000" /></a>  <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Schwerin_Castle_Aerial_View_Island_Luftbild_Schweriner_Schloss_Insel_See.jpg" class="internal" title="Enlarge"></a></div><a 

    href="/wiki/Tourism_in_Germany" title="Tourism in Germany">Tourism in Germany</a> (<a href="/wiki/Schwerin_Palace" title="Schwerin Palace">Schwerin Palace</a>)</div></div></div>
    <div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">Main article: <a href="/wiki/Tourism_in_Germany" title="Tourism in Germany">Tourism in Germany</a></div>
    <ul><li><a href="/wiki/List_of_sights_in_Berlin" title="List of sights in Berlin">List of sights in Berlin</a>
    <ul><li><a href="/wiki/List_of_sights_of_Potsdam" class="mw-redirect" title="List of sights of Potsdam">List of sights of Potsdam</a></li></ul></li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_castles_in_Germany" title="List of castles in Germany">List of castles in Germany</a></li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_cathedrals_in_Germany" title="List of cathedrals in Germany">List of cathedrals in Germany</a></li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_museums_in_Germany" title="List of museums in Germany">List of museums in Germany</a></li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/List_of_tallest_structures_in_Germany" title="List of tallest structures in Germany">List of tallest structures in Germany</
```

The above code is not working because there is a div.
how can I get the same output as above but only li

Comment: You obviously need a more complex use of Soup's API.  Are you asking someone go bring up the source for that page, understand its structure, and write your code for you?  That's not what we do here.    If you want help with this, I would suggest extracting a small (as small as possible anyway) snippet of the raw HTML and then asking a specific question about how to deal with that particular piece of HTML.  Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no steve I am not looking for the code. let me rewrite the question with only the snapshot of the code that is giving thi susse

Comment: What is your desired output are you just looking for li within the class "thumb tright"?

Comment: I am looking for for the li and ul

Comment: Have you explored using existing solutions? I know there's a project which extracts and publishes Wikipedia's tables in machine-readable form, though its name escapes me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup,Tag
import requests

url=r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_tourist_attractions"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = Soup(r.text,"html.parser" )

for ul in soup.findAll('div'):
    print(ul.text)
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        print(li.text)
```